# What could be the causes of this performance regression, and how to investigate it?

Tags: performance, optimization, profiling, performancecounter

### Context

I'm writing some high-performance code for ARM64 using NEON SIMD instructions, which I am trying to further optimize. I only use integer operations, no floating-point. This code is fully CPU- or memory-bound: it does not perform system calls or I/O of any kind (filesystem, networking, or anything else). The code is single-threaded by design -- any parallelism should be handled by calling the code from different CPUs with different arguments. The data working set should be small enough to fit in my CPU's L1 D-cache, and if it overflows a little, it will definitely fit in L2 with lots of space to spare.

My development environment is an Apple laptop with the M1 processor, running macOS; as such, the prime choice for a performance investigation tool is Apple's Instruments. I know VTune has some more advanced features such as top-down microarchitecture analysis, but evidently this isn't available for ARM.

### The problem

I had an idea that, at a high level, works like this: a certain function `f(x, y)` can be broken down into two functions `g()` and `h()`. I can calculate `x2 = g(x)`, `y2 = g(y)` and then `h(x2, y2)`, obtaining the same result as `f(x, y)`. However, it turns out that I compute `f()` many times with different combinations of the same input arguments. By applying all these inputs to `g()` and caching their outputs, I can directly call the output of `h()` with these cached values and save some time recomputing the `g()`-part of `f()`.

#### Benchmarks

I confirmed the basic idea is sound by microbenchmarking with Google Benchmark. If `f()` takes 100 X (where X is some arbitrary unit of time), then each call to `g()` takes 14 X, and a call to `h()` takes 78 X. While it's longer to call `g()` twice then `h()` rather than `f()`, suppose I need to compute `f(x, y)` and `f(x, z)`, which would ordinarily take 200 X. I can instead compute `x2 = g(x)`, `y2 = g(y)` and `z2 = g(z)`, taking 3*14 = 42 X, and then `h(x2, y2)` and `h(x2, z2)`, taking 2*78 = 156 X. In total, I spend 156 + 42 = 198 X, which is already less than 200 X, and the savings would add up for larger examples, up to maximum of 22%, since this is how much less `h()` costs compared to `f()` (assuming I compute `h()` much more often than `g()`). This would represent a significant speedup for my application.

I proceeded to test this idea on a more realistic example: I have some code which does a bunch of things, plus 3 calls to `f()` which, among themselves, use combinations of the same 2 arguments. So, I replace 3 calls to `f()` by 2 calls to `g()` and 3 calls to `h()`. The benchmarks above indicate this should reduce execution time by 3*100 - 2*14 - 3*78 = 38 X. However, benchmarking the modified code shows that execution time **increases** by ~700 X!

I tried replacing each call to `f()` individually with 2 calls to `g()` for its arguments and a call to `h()`. This should increase execution time by 2*14 + 78 - 100 = 6 X, but instead, execution time increases by 230 X (not coincidentally, approximately 1/3 of 700 X).

#### Performance counter results using Apple Instruments

To bring some data to the discussion, I ran both codes under Apple Instruments using the CPU counters template, monitoring some performance counters I thought might be relevant.

For reference, the original code executes in 7.6 seconds (considering only number of iterations times execution time per iteration, i.e. disregarding Google Benchmark overhead), whereas the new code executes in 9.4 seconds; i.e. a difference of 1.8 seconds. Both versions use the exact same number of iterations and work on the same input, producing the same output. The code runs on the M1's performance core, which I assume is running at its maximum 3.2 GHz clock speed.

| Parameter | Original code | New code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Total cycles | 22,199,155,777 | 27,510,276,704 |
| **MAP_DISPATCH_BUBBLE** | **78,611,658** | **6,438,255,204** |
| L1D_CACHE_MISS_LD | 892,442 | 1,808,341 |
| L1D_CACHE_MISS_ST | 2,163,402 | 4,830,661 |
| L1I_CACHE_MISS_DEMAND | 2,620,793 | 7,698,674 |
| INST_SIMD_ALU | 79,448,291,331 | 78,253,076,740 |
| INST_SIMD_LD | 17,254,640,147 | 16,867,679,279 |
| INST_SIMD_ST | 14,169,912,790 | 14,029,275,120 |
| INST_INT_ALU | 4,512,600,211 | 4,379,585,445 |
| INST_INT_LD | 550,965,752 | 546,134,341 |
| INST_INT_ST | 455,541,070 | 455,298,056 |
| INST_ALL | 119,683,934,968 | 118,972,558,207 |
| MAP_STALL_DISPATCH | 6,307,551,337 | 5,470,291,508 |
| SCHEDULE_UOP | 116,252,941,232 | 113,882,670,763 |
| MAP_REWIND | 16,293,616 | 11,787,119 |
| FLUSH_RESTART_OTHER_NONSPEC | 58,616 | 90,955 |
| FETCH_RESTART | 27,417,457 | 28,119,690 |
| BRANCH_MISPRED_NONSPEC | 432,761 | 465,697 |
| L1I_TLB_MISS_DEMAND | 754,161 | 1,492,705 |
| L2_TLB_MISS_INSTRUCTION | 485,702 | 1,217,474 |
| MMU_TABLE_WALK_INSTRUCTION | 486,812 | 1,219,082 |
| BRANCH_MISPRED_NONSPEC | 377,750 | 440,382 |
| INST_BRANCH | 1,194,614,553 | 1,151,040,641 |

Instruments won't let me add all these counters to the same run, so some results are from different runs. However, since the code is fully deterministic and runs the same number of iterations, any differences between runs should be just random noise.

**EDIT**: playing around with Instruments, I found one performance counter that has wildly differing values between the original code and the new code, which is `MAP_DISPATCH_BUBBLE`. Still doing research on what it means, whether it might explain the issues I'm seeing, and how to work around this.

**EDIT 2**: I decided to test this code on other ARM processors I have access to (Cortex-X2 and Cortex-A72). On the Cortex-X2, both versions perform identically, and on the Cortex-A72, there was a small (~1.5%) increase in performance with the new code. So I'm more inclined than ever to believe that I hit an M1 front-end bottleneck.

#### Hypotheses and data analysis

Having faced previous performance problems with this code base before, some ideas sprung to mind:

- **Memory alignment**: SIMD code is sometimes sensitive to memory alignment, particularly for memory-bound code, which I suspect my code may be. However, adding or removing `__attribute__((aligned(64)))` made no difference, so I don't think that's it.
- **D-cache misses**: the new code allocates some new arrays to cache the output of `g()`, so it might lead to more cache misses. And indeed there are 3.6 million more L1 D-cache misses (load + store) than the original code. However, as I've mentioned at the beginning, the working set easily fits into L2. Assuming a 10-cycle L2 cache miss cost, that's only 36 million cycles. At 3.2 GHz, that's just 1.1 ms, i.e. < 0.1% of the observed performance difference.
- **I-cache misses**: a similar situation: there's an extra 5.1 million L1 I-cache misses, but at a 10-cycle cost, we're looking at 1.6 ms, again < 0.1% of the observed performance difference.
- **Inlining/unrolling**: I employ aggressive inlining and loop unrolling on my code, as well as LTO and unity builds, since performance is the #1 priority and code size is irrelevant (unless it affects performance via e.g. I-cache misses). I considered the possibility that the new code might be inlining/unrolling less aggressively due to the compiler hitting some kind of heuristic for maximum code size. This might result in more instructions being executed, such as compares/branches for loops, and `CALL`/`RET` and function prologues/epilogues for function call. However, the table shows that the new code executes a bit fewer instructions of each kind (as I would expect), and of course, in total (`INST_ALL`).

Somehow, the original code simply achieves a higher IPC, and I have no idea why. Also, to be clear: both codes perform the same operation using the same algorithm. What I did was to basically the code for `f()` (a bunch of function calls to other subroutines) between `g()` and `h()`.

### The question

This brings me to my question: what could possibly be making the new code run slower than the old code? What other performance counters could I look at in Instruments to give me insight into this issue?

Beyond answers to this specific question, I'm looking for general advice on how to approach similar problems like this in the future. I've found some books about debugging performance problems, but they generally fall into two camps. The first just describes the profiling process I'm familiar with: find out which functions take the longest to execute and optimize them. The second is represented by books like [Systems Performance: Enterprise and the Cloud](https://www.brendangregg.com/systems-performance-2nd-edition-book.html) and [The Every Computer Performance Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1482657759), and is closer to what I'm looking for. However, they look at system-level issues like I/O, kernel calls, etc.; the kind of code I write is CPU- and maybe memory-bound, with many opportunities to convert to SIMD, and no interaction with the outside world. Basically, I'd like to know how to design meaningful experiments using a profiler and CPU performance counters (cycle counters, cache misses, instructions executed by type such as ALU, memory, etc.) to solve these kinds of performance issues with my code when they arise.

Comment: It looks like the code is clearly compute-bound based on the provided information. The additional time is certainly due to an additional latency between the instructions (modern processors execute instruction in parallel). It can also be due to the saturation of a specific port but processors like the M1 are pretty uniform. This is difficult to track such problem when the code is known, but it is nearly impossible to do that without the code nor the generated assembly. Modern processors are insanely complex, not to mention the M1 is not very well documented on top of that.

Comment: You likely need precise events to track such issues and give a look to the assembly code. I guess the M1 should provides such events. Please provide more information about the code so we can help you (only the hot part is sufficient, a fully reproducible example would be great for such a complex problem).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out a possible source of slowdown that I hadn't considered, instruction latency. My initial reaction is that this is unlikely, as my code has lots of inherent parallelism -- it could be easily ported to a hypothetical NEON unit with 512-bit vectors, and even beyond. Moreover, the M1 has a huge reorder buffer which should ensure enough lookahead to find the required IPC (see [Dougall Johnson](https://dougallj.github.io/applecpu/firestorm.html)'s investigation of the M1 microarchitecture). However, I'll give this some thought as the possible cause.

Comment: As for providing code, it's very difficult: it's proprietary, and the code involved in `f()`/`g()`/`h()` alone numbers in the thousands of lines -- never mind the code of the function that calls them, where the problem manifests itself.

Comment: @JérômeRichard would you please look at the edit I made with a new performance counter result? It's making me suspect of front-end issues.

Comment: Front-end issues sounds right. How big is the compiled code in bytes? How big is the working set? I don't know of a way to log L2 misses, but it's possible those 10-cycle estimates are low... It's unlikely that each L1-cache-miss is taking the 700 cycles this would imply, but I wouldn't completely rule it out if it's missing L2 (which is shared between code and data). Anything on MAP_STALL_DISPATCH, SCHEDULE_UOP, MAP_REWIND, FLUSH_RESTART, L1I_TLB_MISS_DEMAND, L2_TLB_MISS_INSTRUCTION, MMU_TABLE_WALK_INSTRUCTION, or BRANCH_MISPRED_NONSPEC?

Comment: (If I subtract all your INST_* counters from INST_ALL I see a 35% increase in uncategorised operations, which is a bit surprising. Are those branches? Could contribute to front-end issues. M1 has a front-end predictor that can fit 1024 branches (conditional or unconditional) and run them with 1c latency (assuming they go to the same place as last time). If you're exceeding that, you'd get 3c latency. Maybe the extra code size is leading to an extra 2c front-end penalty on every branch? I'd experiment with less inlining.)

Comment: @Dougall thanks for your comments. The code is huge due to inlining and unrolling, which up until now was improving performance (but maybe I've finally reached the limit): `f()` ~ 160 KB, `g()` ~ 20 KB, `h()` ~ 128 KB. I guess it's starting to make sense now: since there's only 192 KB of L1 I-cache, the functions are probably getting evicted and reloaded, over and over again. When I was using `f()` alone, since the "sibling" functions running under the same benchmark are not as large as this, maybe this wasn't as much of an issue.

Comment: @Dougall as for the working set of the application itself, I just added up what I believe are the largest variables and it's < 60 KB, so it should comfortably fit in the L1 D-cache. I'll now run the code under Instruments, test the performance counters you requested, and update the table.

Comment: @Dougall oh, about branches: the code definitely shouldn't have a significant amount of branches -- I would be surprised, given the nature of the code and the heavy use of inlining/unrolling, if > 1% of the instructions were branches, and the majority of these should be easily predicted loops. Probably even fewer, but 1% is a safe bet.

Comment: Puzzling. Might just be a quirk or glitch, but can you also check INST_BRANCH? I'm assuming a code-size issue, but it still doesn't quite add up. You might be able to experiment with compiling multiple copies of f() and calling each in turn to see if deliberately only increasing size also causes this kind of slowdown.

Comment: @Dougall I've added all the requested performance counter results, including INST_BRANCH. I'll try your idea about creating a second copy of `f()` and report back.

Comment: @Dougall did as you asked: on the original code, I created a copy of `f()`, then changed the "main" function being benchmarked, which calls `f()` a few times, replacing every second call to `f()` by a call to the copy. The result: no performance loss due to the copies.

Comment: @Dougall one thing I forgot to mention, although I don't think it's the issue since there appears to be no L1 D-cache pressure: when splitting `f()` between `g()` and `h()` I had to create some new, not so small (8 KB) arrays, which are the cached outputs I mentioned. However, these are already accounted for in the < 60 KB estimate I mentioned earlier. They are saved by `g()` and later loaded by `h()`. My initial theory, before posting here on SO, was that the added stores and loads were responsible for the performance issue I'm seeing.

Comment: Yeah... There are two possible problems that aren't L1D pressure: store->load latency (but the drop in MAP_STALL_DISPATCH implies that it's probably not a latency problem) and memory order violations (ST_MEMORY_ORDER_VIOLATION_NONSPEC). Everything points to front-end, but I'm struggling to imagine what's causing that much of a problem.

Comment: @Dougall I tried ST_MEMORY_ORDER_VIOLATION_NONSPEC as well. 3.1 million events for the original code and 2.1 million for the new code.

Comment: If you're still looking at this issue, there seems to be a very large increase in TLB cache misses. That could definitely cause some slowdown -- I'd encourage you to read up on the Translation Lookaside Buffer (TLB) cache.