# How to interpret Apple M1 performance counters MAP_DISPATCH_BUBBLE, MAP_STALL, MAP_STALL_DISPATCH?

Tags: cpu-architecture, apple-m1, performancecounter

This is related to [another question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75137976/what-could-be-the-causes-of-this-performance-regression-and-how-to-investigate) about an abnormal increase in a particular performance counter. I would like to shine a light on this particular counter and related ones.

So: **what do the performance counters `MAP_DISPATCH_BUBBLE`, `MAP_STALL`, `MAP_STALL_DISPATCH` on the Apple M1 chip measure?**

This is the description given by Instruments of each of these performance counters.

| Performance counter | Description |
| --- | --- |
| MAP_DISPATCH_BUBBLE | Bubble detected in dispatch stage |
| MAP_STALL | Cycles while the Map Unit was stalled for any reason |
| MAP_STALL_DISPATCH | Cycles while the Map Unit was stalled because of Dispatch back pressure |

About the only information I could find related to these counters was [this tweet](https://twitter.com/alanwusx/status/1547633076720635910), which I reproduce here:

> @dougallj
> Hey, do you know what the Map Unit is on the M1? I'm looking at an interpreter that does a lot of indirect branches and Instruments is saying MAP_STALL_DISPATCH accounts for ~50% of total cycles. Apple's tooltip talks about the Map Unit and Dispatch but info is sparse.

Here is the reply:

> The map unit is the frontend "rename" in this diagram. It sits in front of the dispatch queues, which hold uops until they pass into the scheduler.
>
> Each dispatch queue can accept 8 uops/cycle, and "dispatch" (to its schedulers) 1 uop per exec unit/cycle.

This is the diagram in question:

[image: Apple M1 "Firestorm" CPU block diagram]

Finally, a quote from [Dougall Johnson's web site on the Firestorm CPU architecture](https://dougallj.github.io/applecpu/firestorm.html):

> Retirement slots are limited to eight per cycle, which I have called the "retires per cycle" limit, but likely corresponds to a frontend "decode width", rather than a limit related to retirement itself (which I suspect could be either out-of-order, or much wider).

So my working theory about these counters, given their names and descriptions, plus the linked tweet and web page, is this:

1. The Map unit is supposedly the "Rename/Allocate" block on the diagram. It could theoretically fill up at a rate of 8 µops/second.
2. If the Map unit goes idle at any clock cycle, `MAP_STALL` is incremented. I can think of a couple of reasons for this:

   1. I-cache misses, in which case you'd see lots of `L1I_CACHE_MISS_DEMAND` events;
   2. if an instruction cannot be sent to the desired dispatch queue because the queue is full, which should only happen if all of its children schedulers are also full. This, in turn, would happen because none of these schedulers can execute instructions: either the execution units are busy with long latency instructions, or operands are missing (due to dependencies or a data cache miss). Regardless of the cause, I would expect `MAP_STALL_DISPATCH` to increment in this case (due to the full dispatch queue) as well.
3. Finally, `MAP_DISPATCH_BUBBLE`: since the description speaks of a "bubble (...) in dispatch stage", I would interpret this to mean that no instructions were dispatched to the schedulers in a given clock cycle. For this to happen, all dispatch units/schedulers would need to find themselves, in a given clock cycle, in one of the following two situations:

   1. Empty dispatch unit, which is reasonable for some, but not all, of them: say you're running integer code only, then the SIMD units would be empty, and vice-versa. But I don't see how all of the dispatch units would be empty, unless there's a very long latency I-cache miss -- and in that case, you should equally see lots of `MAP_STALL` events (never mind `L1I_CACHE_MISS_DEMAND` events), but not `MAP_STALL_DISPATCH`.
   2. Non-empty dispatch unit, but all children schedulers are full and unable to start execution of any of their instructions. This is a similar situation as case (2.2) above, with similar reasons (i.e. long latency instructions or missing operands), except this time the dispatch unit isn't full.

This should summarize the different possible scenarios:

| I-cache miss | STALL | STALL_DISPATCH | DISPATCH_BUBBLE | Dispatch Q | Schedulers | Cause |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Lots | Lots | Any | Few | Not empty | Not full | Short-term cache miss |
| Lots | Lots | Few | Lots | Empty | Any | Long-term cache miss |
| Few | Few | Few | Few | Not full | Not full | Front-end bound(?) |
| Few | Few | Few | Lots | Halfway | Full | Back-end bound (3.2) |
| Few | Lots | Lots | Lots | Full | Full | Back-end bound (2.2) |

**Does this look reasonable? Can anyone poke holes into any assumptions or conclusions of this theory?**

Comment: I would say `MAP_DISPATCH_BUBBLE` means that *any* of the dispatch queues didn't receive a uop (hence a bubble) in that cycle. A bubble is when a nop is inserted in the input of a pipeline stage, so I'd expect this to mean that the front-end didn't have a uop for at least a dispatch queue. But I'm not familiar with the M1 terminology.

Comment: Interesting. So you think it means that the dispatch queue **didn't receive** a µop in that cycle? I was working under the assumption that it didn't move a µop to a child scheduler.

Comment: Take it with a (large) pinch of salt, I'm not familiar with the M1. But that's what I would assume a dispatch bubble is.